# How do I find the median time?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
severstal_df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(severstal_df['time'], format = '%H:%M:%S')

severstal_df = severstal_df.groupby(['operation', 'date', 'user'])\
                           .duration.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()).reset_index(name = 'duration')

severstal_df['duration_time'] = (pd.Timestamp('today').normalize() + severstal_df['duration']).dt.time

severstal_df['duration_median'] = severstal_df.groupby('operation')\
                                              .apply(severstal_df.median(axis = severstal_df['duration_time']))
```

Gives an error message:

`Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

```
Types:
operation         int64
date             object
user              int64
duration_time    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do share a sample of your data. That'll help us to try solutions to your problem. :-)

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/15tbwjr)